# Dynamic <table> not rendering data

Tags: html, reactjs, jsx

I'm trying to create a dynamic table that renders data inserted based on a format of

```
{headers: ["header1", "header2"], rows: [["data1", "data2"], ["moredata", "wowoso muchdata"]]}
```

Rows is just an array of arrays and each array is a row in the table.

I pass this data into a React component which renders the table. The code is the following:

```
export default class StandardTable extends React.Component<Props, State>{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            tableData: this.props.data
        }
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
            <table id="StandardTable">
                <tbody>
                {this.state.tableData.headers.map(function(header){
                    <th>{header}</th>
                })}
                </tbody>
                <tbody>
                {this.state.tableData.rows.map(function(row){
                    <tr>
                        {row.map(function(rowItem){
                            <td>{rowItem}</td>
                        })}
                    </tr>

                })}
                </tbody>
            </table>
                <style jsx>
                    {`
                    #StandardTable{
                        border: 1px solid black;
                    }`}
                </style>
            </div>
        );
    }




}
```

I am able to console log the data object and all the data is there. It's also iterating through the data in the map functions as I can check in console, but unfortunately the table shows up blank in practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can you try this, no need to return, you can use arrow function

```
        <table id="StandardTable">
            <tbody>
            {this.state.tableData.headers.map((header) => (
                <th>{header}</th>
            ))}
            </tbody>
            <tbody>
            {this.state.tableData.rows.map((row)=>(
                <tr>
                    {row.map((rowItem)=>(
                        <td>{rowItem}</td>
                    ))}
                </tr>

            ))}
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Hope it will work.

Comment: Not the first viable solution, but made it as the best one because using the arrow functions is better practices than throwing in returns. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

It's because you forgot the `return`. Just do this in your map functions:

```
            {this.state.tableData.headers.map(function(header){
                return <th>{header}</th>
            })}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no `return` in `map`

```
this.state.tableData.rows.map(function(row){
                   return( <tr>
                        {row.map(function(rowItem){
                           return <td>{rowItem}</td>
                        })}
                    </tr>)

                })
```